# Constraint relative to Locale parameter in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I need to validate a form field against bad words dictionary (Array for example). So to do this I have to create a new Constraint + ConstraintValidator. It works great, the only problem I have is that I want to have different dictionaries for different locales.

Example:

```
namespace MyNameSpace\Category\MyFormBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ContainsNoBadWordsValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    protected $badWordsEN = array('blabla');
    protected $badWordsFR = array('otherblabla');

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (in_array(strtolower($value), array_map('strtolower', $this->getBadWords()))) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('{{ value }}' => $value));
        }
    }

    protected function getBadWords($locale = 'EN')
    {
        switch ($locale) {
            case 'FR':
                return $this->badWordsFR;
                break;
            default:
                return $this->badWordsEN;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

So how do I pass the locale to Constraint? Or should I implement it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `locale` parameter is a member of the [Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) object.
However, the request object is not created all the time (eg. in a CLI application)
This solution allows you to decouple your validation from the request object, and let your validation to be easily unit-tested.

The `LocaleHolder` is a request-listener which will hold upon creation the `%locale%` parameter and then, switch to the Request locale when the event is triggered.
*Note: The **%locale%** parameter is the **default** parameter defined in config.yml*

Your validator must then get this `LocaleHolder` as a constructor parameter, in order to be aware of the current locale.

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

Here, declare the two services you will need, the `LocaleHolder` and your validator.

```
services:
    acme.locale_holder:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\LocaleHolder
        arguments:
            - "%locale%"
        tags:
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener
                event: kernel.request
                method: onKernelRequest

    acme.validator.no_badwords:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Constraints\NoBadwordsValidator
        arguments:
            - @acme.locale_holder
        tags:
            -
                name: validator.constraint_validator
                alias: no_badwords
```

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\LocaleHolder**</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class LocaleHolder
{
    protected $locale;

    public function __construct($default = 'EN')
    {
        $this->setLocale($default);
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $this->setLocale($request->getLocale());
    }

    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }
}
```

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\Constraints**</kbd>

```
use Acme\FooBundle\LocaleHolder;

class ContainsNoBadwordsValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    protected $holder;

    public function __construct(LocaleHolder $holder)
    {
        $this->holder = $holder;
    }

    protected function getBadwords($locale = null)
    {
        $locale = $locale ?: $this->holder->getLocale();

        // ...
    }
}
```